# Issue with constructors in java

Tags: java, constructor

So I have this constructor in my main class:

```
public class GCTest extends Program {
    GCTest(int x, int y) {
        int gcd = gcd(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
        int num = x / gcd;
        int den = Math.abs(y) / gcd;
        if (y < 0) num = -num;
    }
}
```

and when I call the constructor in my void run(), when I compile it the cmd gives me the following error "Cannot determine the main class" but when I create a new java file that only has the constructor and I compile them using the .; command the program runs fine. What am I doing wrong? I'm kinda new in programming. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.lang.Runtime;
import acm.program.*;

public class GCTest extends Program {
    GCTest(int x, int y){
        int gcd = gcd(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
        int num = x / gcd;
        int den = Math.abs(y) / gcd;
        if (y < 0) num = -num;
    }

    public int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) return a;
        return gcd(b,a%b);
    }

    public void run() {
        Runtime myRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        println("Allocating 10000 Rational objects.");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            new GCTest(i + 1, i + 2);
        }

        long fB = myRuntime.freeMemory();
        println("Free memory before garbage collection = " + fB);
        myRuntime.gc();

        long fA = myRuntime.freeMemory();
        println("Free memory after garbage collection = " + fA);
        println("Garbage collection freed up " + (fA - fB) + " bytes.");
    }
}
```

When I compile and run the posted program I get the "cant determine main class error".
When I compile my GCTest.java with this Rational.java (after I remove the constructor from the GCTest code and replace new GCTest with new Rational( , ) everything runs fine. This is the Rational.java :

```
public class Rational{
public Rational(int x, int y) {
  int gcd = gcd(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
  int num = x / gcd;
  int den = Math.abs(y) / gcd;
  if (y < 0) num = -num;
}
public int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main method?

Comment: Want me to post the whole code? It's not really big.

Comment: You're confusing compiling and running. Also, .; is not a command. It's very unclear what you're doing. But there is no main method in the class you posted, so Java can't run it.

Comment: There. It's an exercise about garbage collection.

Comment: The error appears when I execute the javac -cp acm.jar GCTest.java

Comment: where is your main method?

Answer (score 2):

You typically see this error when you forget to include the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

in your program, which you did.  Try something like this:

```
public class GCTest extends Program {
   ..
   ..
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
       new GCTest(...).run();
   }

}
```

`main(..)` is a special method that tells Java where your program begins.

Comment: The teachers at my uni haven't told us to use this line in our program. We only type extends Program or GraphicsProgram or ConsoleProgram and then followed by public void run() :/

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your Program class is an abstract class that implements the following line:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  ...
}
```

This is the entry point for your application. Without posting this code, I will guess that it then forces your extending class to implement the `run` method. thus the main entry point calls `run` on itself to kick off your program. Something like this

```
public abstract class Program {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        this.run();
     }

     public abstract void run();

}
```

You are compiling with the following command:

```
javac -cp acm.jar GCTest.java
```

so you are telling the compiler to add acm.jar to your classpath, and ONLY compile GCTest.java

I am unsure with what you posted what your actual error is, but for now navigate to your source folder and run

```
javac -cp acm.jar *.java
```

and see if that helps

Comment: Only thing I am saying is that I never had to use the public static void main(String [] args) line before in my programs and they all just ran fine. When I run javac -cp acm.jar GCTest.java it compiles just fine but when I run java -cp .;acm.jar GCTest it gives me this problem that it cant determine the main class.

Comment: your public static void main is in the code your professors provided you. It lives in Program, ConsoleProgram, etc.

Comment: your first compile command makes sense. your second one does not. you want javac not java

Comment: The second command is not for compiling, it's for running the program.

Comment: Just to make things clear. This only happens when I try to run the compiled code I posted above. When I make a second .java file in which I only put the constructor, all run fine.

Comment: "The error appears when I execute the javac -cp acm.jar GCTest.java" you are confusing then, when you say this is where the error occurs.

Comment: what exactly is in your seperate file? you say just the constructor, so you are saying it works when you remove the run() function? Please post this second file

Comment: Updated the original post. Basically Ii just move the Constructor method from gctest to a separate file

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. When you do new GCTest, you are creating multiple copies of the main entry point. When you create a new Rational, you are creating multiple copies of the object that holds your gcd code only. So the first version is causing your issue, though I'm unsure why java would care since it will only execute the first main method passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an clarification:

The program posted by user3083578 is using acm.program package. You do not need to write your own main class if your class extends Program class. You only need to implement run() method your main class.

The documentation of the package can be found in here: 
http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts/jtf/rationale/ProgramPackage.html

You use `javac -cp acm.jar GCTest.java` to compile the program.

After compiling, if you need to run your program, you can simply use

```
java GCTest
```

Update:

The correct way of running the program is

```
java -cp .:acm.jar GCTest
```

I can run the program if I take away the constructor you declared (and all the depended lines). I don't know if acm.package support declaring your own constructor. Also, I could not get `.;` working and I think what you meant was `.:`.

Comment: Exactly. But what am I doing wrong? I have never gotten this problem before.

Comment: That doesn't work. I have to include the -cp .;acm.jar. That's what they have taught us at uni.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried `java GCTest`. It's not working. I am trying to see if `-cp .;acm.jar` works on my computer. When my college was teaching this course, we used eclipse. The IDE handles compiling and running of the program. We just need to add the jar file to the build path. You can certainly try eclipse as an option.

Comment: It has to work on the cmd. I am familiar with Eclipse but its use is forbidden at this time. The procedure I follow is always the same.
1. Write the .java file.
2. Put it in the same folder as acm.jar .
3. Run javac -cp acm.jar ***.java.
4. Run java -cp .;acm.jar ***
and it always works.

Comment: I can run the program if I take away the constructor you declared (and all the depended lines). I don't know if acm.package support declaring your own constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To compile a java program you just have to pass that the program has no error.
But, to run your java program you must have to set an entry point to show the machine from where your program should run.
I hope you understand now what's happening for you now.
you must have a

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

or

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

method in one of your class to set that entry point for your program.